# C++ Boolean Value always incorrectly returns true in 2-3 Tree Search

Tags: c++, search, tree, boolean

I'm literally ripping my hair out on this one fellas. Here's the problem. I've hard coded a 2-3 Tree and verified that it works with the use of an inorder traversal function that outputs the values of the node it's currently in. So I know the tree is built correctly.

```
 Node *r;
  Node zero,one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten;
  r = &zero;

          //Root
 zero.small = 50;
 zero.large = 90;
 zero.left = &one;       //Child node to the left
 zero.middle = &four;    //Child node in the middle
 zero.right = &seven;    //Child node to the right

  //Left Tree
 one.small = 20;
 one.large = NULL;
 one.left = &two;
 one.middle = NULL;
 one.right = &three;

 two.small = 10;
 two.large = NULL;
 two.left = NULL;
 two.middle = NULL;
 two.right = NULL;

 three.small = 30;
 three.large = 40;
 three.left = NULL;
 three.middle = NULL;
 three.right = NULL;

  //Middle Tree
 four.small = 70;
 four.large = NULL;
 four.left = &five;
 four.middle = NULL;
 four.right = &six;

 five.small = 60;
 five.large = NULL;
 five.left = NULL;
 five.middle = NULL;
 five.right = NULL;

 six.small = 80;
 six.large = NULL;
 six.left = NULL;
 six.middle = NULL;
 six.right = NULL;

  //Right Tree
 seven.small = 120;
 seven.large = 150;
 seven.left = &eight;
 seven.middle = &nine;
 seven.right = &ten;

 eight.small = 100;
 eight.large = 110;
 eight.left = NULL;
 eight.middle = NULL;
 eight.right = NULL;

 nine.small = 130;
 nine.large = 140;
 nine.left = NULL;
 nine.middle = NULL;
 nine.right = NULL;

 ten.small = 160;
 ten.large = NULL;
 ten.left = NULL;
 ten.middle = NULL;
 ten.right = NULL;

 cout<<"inorder traversal for debug"<<endl;
 inOrder(*r);
```

Output would be: 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100 110 120 130 140 150 160

So that proves the tree is built correctly. I've been asked to modify the code to search for a value in the tree. so I wrote this function below, that's essentially the inorder traversal function minus the outputs and a simple if statement that returns TRUE if the search key is found in the tree.

```
bool retrieve(Node r, int key)
{
 if (r.left)
    retrieve(*r.left, key);
 if (r.small)
 {
     if (r.small == key)
    {
        cout<<"The node: "<<r.small<<" is equal to search key: "<<key<<endl; //for debug purposes
        return true;
    }
 }
 if (r.middle)
    retrieve(*r.middle, key);
 if (r.large)
 if (r.right)
    retrieve(*r.right, key);  
}
```

The user is prompted for a number to search for (int key), and upon entry enters an if statement

```
if (retrieve(*r, key))
 {
     cout<<key<<" is found!"<<endl;
 }
 else
     cout<<key<<" is not found!"<<endl;
```

Now the problem is that this seems logically sound to me, and yet when I enter the value "85" (which is not located on the tree AT ALL), the program outputs "85 is found!". **Notice how it didn't output the COUT statement I have in the function.**`cout<<"The node: "<<r.small<<" is equal to search key: "<<key<<endl;` I've debugged and stepped through the program and no matter what the bool function (retrieve) always returns true... What? So I switched the if statement in the bool function to return false (just for debugging purposes) upon entering "60" (which IS located on the tree), the boolean function STILL returns true. I've tried several combinations of slightly different code but to no avail.. What the heck is going on??

Thanks in advance,

Tyler

Comment: you never return false from `retrieve`. only true. Where should the false come from?

Comment: I had figured that might be the problem, but I'm not sure where to place "return false;" without exiting the traversal of the tree prematurely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never return a value, except in the `if (r.small == key)` branch.

From [2–3 tree - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2%E2%80%933_tree), I would say your code should compare the `key` with the `small` and `large` key first and depending on the comparison return the result from `retrieve(*r.left/middle/right, key)`.

Something along these lines (*untested*)

```
if (key < r.small)
    return retrieve(*r.small, key);

if (key == r.small)
    return TRUE;

if (r.right == NULL)
    return retrieve(*r.middle, key);

if (key < r.large)
    return retrieve(*r.middle, key);

if (key == r.large)
    return TRUE;

return retrieve(*r.right, key);
```

Comment: Hmm.. I'll try to implement that in a second, I also noticed that when `return true;` is finally hit in my `if (r.small == key)`, instead of exiting the function, it simply keeps recursing through the function. Isn't return supposed to return the value and exit the function?

Comment: @TylerDean It does return to the caller, which could be the original caller or just another `retrieve()`, depending on how deep the recursion is. So, it might take some returns until you hit the outermost caller.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first check if the key is found in the current node in either small or large, and if it is, return true. if it is not you need to recursively call retrieve on each of the contained nodes, and if any of them return true, return true.  If your function has not returned yet you need to return false.

Answer (score 0):

You need an initial test to see if the recursion should stop because you are at a least node.

```
// precondition: current is not 0
// returns: true or false. If true, location is set to the node 
// where it was found.
bool DoSearch(Node *current, int key, Node *location)
{
 /*
  * Is key in current?
  */
if (current->smallValue == key || (current->isThreeNode() 
       && current->largeValue == key)) {

    location = current;
    return true;

} else if ((current->isLeafNode())) {

    location = current;
    return false;
 /*
  *  Does current have two keys?
  */
} else if (current->isThreeNode()){

    if (key < current->smallValue) {

        DoSearch(key, current->leftChild, location);

    }  else if (key < current->largeValue) {

        DoSearch(key, current->middleChild, location);

    } else {

        DoSearch(key, current->rightChild, location);
    }

} else { // ...or only one?

     if (key < current->smallValue) {

        DoSearch(key, current->leftChild, location);

    }  else {

        DoSearch(key, current->rightChild, location);
    }
}
}
```